# Is there a more detailed/up-to-date reference for parameters to Wordpress plugin API?

Tags: php, api, wordpress

I had tried to use the example code [here](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/interacting-with-wordpress-plug-in-theme-api/) to fetch a long list of plugins, with only certain fields. However, the filter doesn't work as expected. According to documentation:

> "fields – an array with possible fields (listed below) as keys and
>   true or false value to return data for that field or not. The fields
>   that are included make up the properties of the returned object above.
>   The possible fields are (default set to true, unless otherwise
>   stated):"

The listed fields don't seem to work, with array values set, un-set, true, or false. It appears the API may have changed, without updated documentation? Is there any more detailed documentation, preferably one that shows how to query for multiple slugs/names/etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is a bit limited, but there's one useful feature I noticed:

http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/nextgen-gallery will give php-variable of the data about nextgen gallery. Similarly, http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/nextgen-gallery.json gives it in JSON format, and http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/nextgen-gallery.xml gives xml format.